# Having to delete and add printer every time I print. How to fix?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb, printing, hp

Every time I need to print I connect my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS to HP LJ 1018 printer over USB and then I expect it printing once I click printer icon (or OK button in printer dialog).

But after I switched from version 14 to 16 LTS this does not work anymore - the printing job will sit forever in the queue and will not react to clicking on green triangle button. What works is deleting printer from the system, switching the printer off and on, adding the same printer back into system, hitting the print button.
If I disconnect the printer I would have to repeat the entire hassle again. Is there a cure to this issue?

Comment: Anyone?..........

Comment: Hm... not a single answer... really? This is why Linux is still not ready for desktops - too many issues and virtually no support.

Answer (score 0):

I know how it feels when things don't work as expected on Linux. Since you're a lucky owner of an HP printer, there's a solution for you.

1. go to [HPLIP download page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip)
   2.grab HPLIP download for your distro
2. `cd` to the downloaded script location
3. `$chmod u+x hplip-3.xy.zw.run && ./hplip-3.xy.zw.run`